# Problem with installing sqlite3 module for python 2.6 on an ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python, sqlite

I need to run the sqlite3 module on python 2.6 in an ubuntu system. How do I install this module for Python 2.6?

Somehow I don't have this module, it raises the error:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Mar 20 2010, 18:48:10) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in

That is not the python that comes with Ubuntu.  either:

- Install `libsqlite3-dev` and re-build that version of python, or
- use /usr/bin/python

Comment: ohh, I have not known that the python 2.6 is preinstalled with ubuntu 9. thanks for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably `sudo aptitude install python2.6-sqlite`, depending on which version of Ubuntu you're running.  You may need to update your packages first if you don't do that regularly (`sudo aptitude update`).

---

Do you have the appropriate sqlite3 packages installed?  If you do `dpkg -l | egrep sqlite3` I'd expect at least 3 packages to show up, including `sqlite3` and `libsqlite3-0`.  You may also need `python2.6-pysqlite2`.

Try `sudo aptitude install python2.6-pysqlite2 sqlite3 libsqlite3-0`

Comment: hi Cry, it is the same error. There is nothing changed. My ubuntu version is: Ubuntu 9.10
                - the Karmic Koala - released in October 2009 and supported until April 2011.